# Как сохранить файл, а после еще раз его открыть?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Я создаю отчет в формате xlsx, в некоторых колонках используются мной написанные формулы, но в конце к отчету нужно приложить графики, тк данные для графика находятся в колонках с формулами, то я сохраняю файл(потому что если заново не открывать файл вместо значений будут формулы)

```
workbook = Workbook()
...    
workbook.save(filename="Отчет.xlsx")
workbook.close()
```

а потом заново его открываю, достаю данные, строю графики и вставляю их в xlsx.

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename="Отчет.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

Но такой механизм не работает, формулы остаются формулами, а не значениями. Но если после создания отчета закрыть программу, открыть файл нажать Ctrl  + S(сохранение), а после запустить ее с момента

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename="Отчет.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

то все работает. Как это исправить ?

Comment: Никак, openpyxl не умеет считать формулы